# Can't connect to remote Postgres DB Using PGAdmin III via SSH Tunnelling

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect remotely to a PostgreSQL DB using PGAdmin III on VPS I setup on Digital Ocean.

*FYI I am using SSH Keys to connect to my instance, no passwords.*

I have setup the SSH tunnel like so:
`ssh -L 3333:remote.server.com:5432 myuser@remote.server.com`

Then in the postgresql.conf I have modified the listening addresses to:
`listen_addresses='*'`

Just in case, I also added to pg_hba.conf the line :
`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` 
however I still get the same error so I believe this is useless.

Finally in PGAdmin, I create new connection using
host: localhost
port: 3333  (as per local tunnel option above)
username: myuser
Then on SSH tunnel tab, I have a checkmark on use SSH tunneling
tunnel host: remote.server.com
tunnel post: 5432
username: myuser
identity_file: I point to my local id_rsa.pub file
and I enter my passphrase.

I get the following error:
**SSH error: Error when starting up SSH session with error code -13**

I added the -v option to the SSH tunnel creation line and I see "authentication successful" as well as "local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3333"